# ROBLOX - How would I move the player 8 studs, for 20 miliseconds smoothly (so tweening), in the direction the player is facing?

Tags: roblox

How would I move the player 8 studs, for 20 miliseconds smoothly (so tweening), in the direction the player is facing?

```lua
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    --[This is because this is a localscript in a tool]
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local isGliding = false;

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    isGliding = not isGliding;
    local char = script.Parent.Parent; --The tool gets inside of the char when activated
    local humanoidRootPart = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart");
    coroutine.wrap(function()
    while true do
       humanoidRootPart.Positon += humanoidRootPart.LookVector * 8;
       wait(0.3)
       if isGliding == false then 
             break;
         end
       end
    end)()
end)
```

Something like that probably. This should be in a ServerScript under the tool.

Comment: Players.{my username}.Backpack.Uppercut.Script:7: LookVector is not a valid member of Part "Workspace.{my username}.HumanoidRootPart"

Comment: Oh sorry, change it to .CFrame.LookVector